# Ionic + Firebase - how to retrieve data after UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I created profiles (complementary information) in the Firebase `Database` considering the UID of the users already registered (with the Email / password method). So, the scheme looked like this:

[image]

And it's working fine for when I need to limit data access to just the respective user who generated them.
But now I have an anonymous user, who needs to read these data, but I can't get the values of the keys "nome", "latitude", "longitude", etc.
My difficulty is to insert the first node, which is the UID, into the anonymous query path.

Here's the code snippet  I try to do:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Perfil } from '../../models/perfil';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html',
})
export class MapPage {

  $key: any;
  $userId: string;
  perfilList: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, db: AngularFireDatabase) {

    this.perfilList = db.list("/perfil/" + this.$userId).valueChanges(); // => Here is my problem!
  }
```

And this is the Perfil class:

```
export interface Perfil{
    $userId?: string;
    $key?: string;
    nome: string;
    categoria : string;
    endereco: string;
    latitude: string;
    longitude:string;
    file: string;
    descricao: string;
}
```

This code doesn't display an error, but also doesn't return anything, this way in map.html:

```
<ion-item *ngFor = "let p of perfilList | async">
  {{p.nome}}
</ ion-item>
```

Comment: you have declared `perfilList` in ts file and are looping through `profileList`.. Its a typo

Comment: Sorry... it was a typo when posting the question. The code is perfilList on the loop. I have fixed it.